# Improving accuracy of water lead test

Tags: water, physical-chemistry, home-experiment, evaporation

Home water tests for lead have an accuracy of about 15 ppb. If I first do a gentle/slow boil for one hour (hot plate under a glass beaker of water) to reduce 2000 mL to 20 mL, will I then effectively be able to detect 0.15 ppb?

My goal is really just 1 ppb.

My main concern now is that any lead might adhere to the glass
(though I think these home tests have a reagent which helps
dissolve lead in case of this) so, if this is truly a problem,
is there a better beaker material or boiling method to use?

Of course, if improvement were this easy, I would expect the
test kits to already be recommending it, so I am probably making
some mistake.  Please explain it.

Comment: I mean the test for non VOC salts is to literally burn the filter paper at 600C so I don't think you are going wrong concentrating the water. I do think your method should work

Comment: You might have another approach, which involves using household acid (lemon juice) to enhance recovery. The relevant publication is [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.est.0c07614#). The article is: Challenges of Detecting Lead in Drinking Water Using at-Home Test Kits
Rebecca Kriss, Kelsey J. Pieper, Jeffrey Parks, and Marc A. Edwards
Environmental Science & Technology 2021 55 (3), 1964-1972,
DOI: 10.1021/acs.est.0c07614

Comment: Of course I do not know the origin of the water to be analyzed. But reducing  a water volume from $2000$ mL to $20$ ml is not so easy as it looks, because boiling tap water does usually produce a deposit of calcium carbonate, which may adsorb the lead ions $\ce{Pb^{2+}}$ during its precipitation.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt The lemon juice is basically the "reagent which helps dissolve lead" that I mentioned, so yes, of course that additionally should be optimized, but my question here is focused instead on getting rid of molecules that are not lead.

Comment: @Maurice I think your point about the calcium carbonate is the key problem since there are typically a million times more calcium atoms than lead atoms (plus we have "hard water" here!), but hoping for a more official answer.  Maybe there is even a trick that someone knows to dissolve all the mineral deposits for an accurate "color strip" test...

Comment: @bobuhito. If the solution is totally evaporated, a powder will be obtained containing all $\ce{CaCO3}$ plus a rather tiny amount of lead. Now redissolving this powder in the minimum amount of diluted nitric acid (or citric acid) can give you a solution containing calcium and lead, where the test for lead can be  carried out.

Comment: Acid should bring the metals into solution.  Find out if other metals found in water *interfere* with lead analysis.